# @Html.ValidationMessageFor did not work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have a two model classes which have relationship of one to many.

```
public class CycleType
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cycle is required.")]
    public int CycleTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cycle Type is required.")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Cycle Type may not be longer than 20 characters")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<CycleModel> CycleModels { get; set; }
}

public class CycleModel
{
    public int CycleModelID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cycle Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cycle is required.")]
    public int CycleTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Model is required.")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Model may not be longer than 20 characters")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public virtual CycleType CycleType { get; set; }
}
```

Razor file.

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CycleTypeID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">            
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CycleTypeID,
                                (SelectList)ViewBag.CycleType,
                                "Select Cycle Type",
                              new { id = "ddlCycleType" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CycleTypeID)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
    </div>
```

1)Fist of my problem is, Validaion function did not fire when I choose select cycle type and it only give error back as

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'CycleTypeID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

2)Second problem is, When I choose one of the cycle type and put value to model more than 20 characters so that validator could check as I expected. But I get the same error message again.

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'CycleTypeID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is a bug in Asp.net MVC due to which the validations don't work for DropDownListFor and TextAreaFor extension methods.

You can check the details at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576

So, you will need to make use of HTML.DropDownList instead of DropDownListFor and then your validations will work as expected.

**Update**

From your controller, pass this

```
ViewBag.CycleTypeId = new SelectList(db.CycleTypes, "CycleTypeId", "Type"); // db is ur context instance
```

And in View use this

```
@Html.DropDownList("CycleTypeId", String.Empty)
```

**More Update**

There is one more work-around for this problem.

Just use your original code of `DropDownListFor`. And then just make use of class property in it like following

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CycleTypeID,
                            (SelectList)ViewBag.CycleType,
                            "Select Cycle Type",
                          new { id = "ddlCycleType", @class = "required" })
```

This will make the validation work, but it will display the default message of *The field is required*. But else will work as you expect it to be.

I guess this is a better solution and good one for your requirements.

Comment: Thank for your helpful solution @Pankaj Upadhyay. I think HTML.DropDownList cannot load collection of data like "(SelectList)ViewBag.CycleType". So could you please tell me best solution.

Comment: I have updated the answer with DropDownList usage. Let me know if it doesn't work. Can't test it on my system right now

Comment: thank you so much @Pankaj Upadhyay, It is work, but one issue is that it could not make one of the items to be dynamically selected according to existing value. Which I could make by using " @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CycleTypeID,
 ...". Thank you

Comment: You can do that too , just pass this `ViewBag.CycleTypeId = new SelectList(db.CycleTypes, "CycleTypeId", "Type", yourModel.CycleTypeId);` which adds one more parameter for selection

Comment: By using your code, i can make dropdownlist to display and auto- selected as I expected, But As for validation it still have the same problem. Any way thank for your very helpful guidance @Pankaj Upadhyay [My Source code](http://www.mediafire.com/?4c2bt14fgteq3ms)

Comment: I have added one more update to the answer and i think this will solve all your problems and will be better.

Answer (score 3):

Why I answer my own question is I don't want anyone to face the same problem like I already found.

First of all, Let me say to @Pankaj Upadhyay that, I really appreciate his great help. I really thank you very much @Pankaj Upadhyay.

Finally I can solve my problem by getting continuous help from @Pankaj Upadhyay.

```
@model CyclingClubSystem.Models.CycleModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;

}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>CycleModel</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CycleModelID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CycleTypeID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">            
        @*Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CycleTypeID,
                                (SelectList)ViewBag.CycleType,
                                "Select Cycle Type",
                           new { id = "ddlCycleType", @class = "required" })*@

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CycleTypeID,
                        (SelectList)ViewBag.CycleType,
                        "Select Cycle Type",
                      new { id = "ddlCycleType"})

        @*Html.DropDownList("CycleType", "Select Cycle Type")*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CycleTypeID)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller Class

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int CycleModelID)
    {
        CycleModel cycleModel = unitOfWork_CycleModel.GenericTEntityRepository.GetByID(CycleModelID);
        //ViewBag.CycleType = new SelectList(unitOfWork_cycleType.GenericTEntityRepository.Get(orderBy: CycleTypes => CycleTypes.OrderBy(CycleType => CycleType.Type)), "CycleTypeID", "Type", cycleModel.CycleTypeID);
        ViewBag.CycleType = new SelectList(unitOfWork_cycleType.GenericTEntityRepository.Get(orderBy: CycleTypes => CycleTypes.OrderBy(CycleType => CycleType.Type)), "CycleTypeID", "Type");
        return View(cycleModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(CycleModel  _CycleModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            unitOfWork_CycleModel.GenericTEntityRepository.Update(_CycleModel);
            unitOfWork_CycleModel.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CycleType = new SelectList(unitOfWork_cycleType.GenericTEntityRepository.Get(orderBy: CycleTypes => CycleTypes.OrderBy(CycleType => CycleType.Type)), "CycleTypeID", "Type");
        return View(_CycleModel);
    }
```

Finally , What I Found out ,the main reason which cause error, is that I forget to put that code at [Controller Edit Post method]

```
ViewBag.CycleType = new SelectList(unitOfWork_cycleType.GenericTEntityRepository.Get(orderBy: CycleTypes => CycleTypes.OrderBy(CycleType => CycleType.Type)), "CycleTypeID", "Type");
```

Why I can solve my problem is I get the contiuous guidance from @Pankaj Upadhyay.

Comment: +1 for letting us know what the solution for your purpose was. This helped me as well. So thank you too, @Frank Myat Thu!